# Caching test data in parameterized fixtures

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

I have various test cases that use common data. I use `pytest` fixtures to cache test data and speed-up the test.

For example:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def data():
    large_data = download('XYZ')
    return large_data

def test_foo(data):
    pass

def test_bar(data):
    pass
```

I would like to extend the test to two datasets. A brute-force solution is:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def data1():
    large_data = download('XYZ')
    return large_data

@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def data2():
    large_data = download('ABC')
    return large_data

def test_foo1(data1):
    pass

def test_foo2(data2):
    pass

def test_bar1(data1):
    pass

def test_bar2(data2):
    pass
```

Now the issue is that `test_bar` is generic.  In the sense that the testing procedure is independent of the data.  Therefore it is a bad idea to duplicate that.

So, I decided to use indirect parameters as follows:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def data(request):
    if request.param == 1:
       large_data = download('XYZ')
    if request.param == 2:
       large_data = download('ABC')
    return large_data

@pytest.mark.parametrize('data', [1], indirect=True)
def test_foo1(data):
    pass

@pytest.mark.parametrize('data', [2], indirect=True)
def test_foo2(data):
    pass

@pytest.mark.parametrize('data', [1, 2], indirect=True)
def test_bar(data):
    pass
```

But now I lose the caching advantages.  The data is downloaded for ever test.  How can I tell pytest to cache the datta for parameterized fixture?

Comment: The problem is obviously the test order - as the fixture is called with different parameters, it cannot be called only once in the module, as it is usually done with module-scoped fixtures. The best option is probably to cache the data and reuse it on next access.

Answer (score 0):

I found a (non-ideal) solution.  The idea is to defined a single fixture for each test data (which does not scale well) and then use a 'wrapper' parameterized fixture to return their value.

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def data1():
    large_data = download('XYZ')
    return large_data

@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def data2():
    large_data = download('ABC')
    return large_data

@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def data(request):
    
    return request.getfixturevalue(request.param)

def test_foo1(data1):
    pass

def test_foo2(data2):
    pass

@pytest.mark.parametrize('data', ['data1', 'data2'], indirect=True)
def test_bar(data):
    pass
```

I've verified that (at least in this example) each data set is downloaded once and only once.  Yet, I'd be curious to know if there are 'cleaner' solutions.